# Fix broken PDF Link in Google Scholar

Tags: pdf, google-scholar

Does anyone know how to update or fix a PDF link in Google Scholar once it has become broken?

I have co-authored some papers, but when I got a job at a new school the old one shut down my old institutional website.  I now keep my papers on a Google Site, but they don't seem to be getting re-indexed on Scholar (maybe because it is not a .edu site).

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit a website with academic articles to Google Scholar (see [Inclusion - Scholar Help](https://support.google.com/scholar/troubleshooter/2898950?hl=en)).

They specify:

> We accept journal papers, conference papers, technical reports,
>   dissertations, pre-prints, post-prints, and abstracts.

If your new institution hosts your papers as part of your CV or something to that effect, however, you might have an easier time of getting the record updated (see [Google scholar missing paper issue clarified](http://phylogenomics.blogspot.com/2012/01/google-scholar-missing-paper-issue.html)) since Google Scholar points out that they do not correct individual entries:

> We're not currently able to perform manual correction on individual
>   entries in our database since the indexing is done automatically by
>   robots.